# How to copy a Watson retrieve-and-rank solr collection on Bluemix

Tags: solr, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

We have a large Solr collection on Watson's Retrieve and Rank service that I need to copy to another collection.  Is there any way to do this in Retrieve and Rank?  I know Solr has backup and restore capability, but it uses the file system and I don't think I have access to that in Bluemix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to do this, beyond the brute force approach of just fetching every doc in the index and adding the contents to a different collection. (And even this would be limited to only letting you fetch the fields that you have stored in the first collection).